# To get data from table in script from sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am using sql server 2005

I have a table [say tblHistory] and this table contains 100 rows. 
I have created the same table at the server, but the table doesn't have the data, I want data from tblHistory to convert into

INSERT INTO tblHistory ------

so that I could run the script on the server to fill the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a linked server between the two servers and then you do something like this

```
INSERT INTO tblHistory
select * from LinkedServerNAme.DatabaseName.SchemaName.tblHistory
```

To add a linked server read this  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

BTW you can also use OPENROWSET, OPENDATASOURCE, SSIS or  bcp out and bcp in

Answer (score 1):

To generate all the INSERT INTO statements you need based on table data, take a look at this project: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sqlinsertupdategenerator.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question... you just want to copy the contents of one table into another?

```
 INSERT INTO newTable SELECT * FROM tblHistory
```

Answer (score 0):

If the new table doesn't already exist, you can use SELECT INTO:

```
SELECT *
  INTO new_table
  FROM tblHistory
```

But that's the caveat - it has to be a new table, no data already in there.

Otherwise, use:

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT x.* --preferrable to actually define the column list than use *
  FROM OLD_TABLE x
```

Comment: Quote: "I have created the same table at the server, but the table doesn't have the data"

Comment: @froadie: Yes, but my point was if there's no data in the new table, it could be deleted & recreated using the statement above.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the SSMS Tools Pack - one of its feature is the ability to generate those INSERT scripts you're looking for!

Get the SSMS Tool Pack from [this site](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) - it's an add-in for SQL Server Management Studio - highly recommended!